# Handle push notifications with opening ViewController in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller, onesignal

I have TabBarController with few tabs. 
In each tab there is NavigationController with ViewController that has TableView and cells. When user presses cell - he get DetailedViewController.

What I want to get - is to open DetailedViewController when my app receives push notification.

I use OneSignal and my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate looks like (*you see that I have itemID which i want to pass to DetailedViewController*)

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(
            launchOptions,
            appId: API_KEY,
            handleNotificationAction : {
                (result) in 
                    if additionalData!["itemID"] != nil {
                        let itemID = Int(additionalData!["itemID"] as! String)
                        if(itemID! > 0) {

                        if(self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil) {
                            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
                                tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
                                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            })
                        }

                    }
                 }
               }
       }
    )
```

1. This code is not working for some reason - I don't get to desired
   tab with ViewController needed
2. I don't know how to open DetailedViewController right from TabBarController
3. When i finally will get to DetailedViewController - what will happen when i press back button on it? There was no ViewController with list of items - where I will navigate in that case?
4. is that code going to use memory well?

Comment: Is there a reason for dismissing the `rootViewController`? Why not simply present your desired tab controller on it? That way, at least your back button will work (once you get everything else working)

Comment: Because when app is running and is receives notification - what should happen if i won't dismiss presented ViewController? It will open new one, eating more memory - am i wrong?

Comment: Simply change your rootViewController to your desired View Controller

Comment: @Mannopson can you show the right way to do it for case with NavigationController and TabBarController as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Firstly instantiate your `TabBarController`

```
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
```

And change your `rootViewController`

```
    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

You can also customize a global `tintColor` right here:

```
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Finally set your selected index:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

That's it: It should work. Let me know if it's works!

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1

    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```